# Wrong number or types of arguments error in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql

The issue is as below (the below steps are to mimic the problem that happening in our development environment)

1. I created a PL/SQL package TEST with procedure TEST_PROC with a single argument.

   ```
   create or replace package test is
       procedure test_proc ( a varchar2);
   end test;

   create or replace package body test is
       procedure test_proc ( a varchar2) IS
   BEGIN
       insert into temp (x) values (a);
   END;
   end test;
   ```
2. I called this procedure from forms in When-button-pressed trigger and it compiles fine.

   ```
   TEST.TEST_PROC('a').
   ```
3. Now, the requirement is to add another argument to the procedure TEST and I did that as below.

   ```
   create or replace package test is
       procedure test_proc ( a varchar2, b varchar2);
   end test;

   create or replace package body test is
   procedure test_proc ( a varchar2, b varchar2) IS
   BEGIN
       insert into temp (x, y) values (a, b);
   END;
   end test;
   ```
4. I called this procedure from forms in When-button-pressed trigger as below but it throws error
   'Wrong number or types of arguments in call to test_proc.

   ```
   TEST.TEST_PROC('a','b').
   ```

I closed and reopened the forms, connected to DB again.
Dropped the entire package and recreated again with 2 parameters but I still get this error in forms but compiles Ok within pl/sql.

Could some one please help me understand what's happening?

Comment: Number of arguments is easy to check - there should be exactly two of them. What about their datatypes? Did you really use code you posted ("test" proc, "a" and "b" as values you passed, etc.)? Were you passing something different that's not a string, and Oracle failed to implicitly convert it to one?

Comment: Yes, I have used the exact code in forms and package that I have shared here.

Comment: In Forms, are you connected to the same schema/database that contains that package?

Comment: It appears that whatever the image of pl/sql package that forms use initially is not changing.

Comment: In Forms, are you connected to the same schema/database that contains that package - Yes, can confirm this as form compiles fine if I remove the 2nd parameter

Comment: I'd expect that form compilation would **fail** if you remove the 2nd parameter, not succeed. Hm. That usually doesn't happen. Sorry to ask, but - did you DOUBLE CHECK that you really are connected to the same database/schema?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm I'm connected to same DB/schema...because when I drop the package 'TEST' and compile the same form I get an error "identifier  'TEST.TEST_PROC' must be declared". I then recreate package with 2 parameters and get the same error (wrong arguments or type)  when called from forms with 2 parameters. BUT if I change that to single parameter in forms and compile, it compiles ok....strange

Comment: Managed to find the root cause. The issue and fix explained here https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2640375_1.html

Comment: Aha, bug it is. Flushing the shared pool fixes it. OK, thank you for letting us know, I'm glad you found the culprit!